# Create persistent Team Meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-teams

Here's my use case. I want to create multiple Team meetings which would be joined by a group on a certain day. I would also want the group, if they prefer, to reuse the same meeting link for all subsequent instances so that they don't need to set up the meeting et al again. What's the best way to go about this? Should I just create a bunch of Team meetings and then just share the links to these meetings with the groups since I believe Teams allows joining old meetings? Is there a way to automate this since going through [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/automate-multiple-meetings-creation-on-teams/9ce5c9c7-86ca-406a-9edb-16b9beb49812) community post, it doesn't appear that there's a way to *automate* Teams meeting creation without resorting to MSFT's [Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams meeting links never expire. All you need to do is create a meeting and send the link to the attendees before the meeting each time or they go to the previous link on their own.
Creating recurring meetings is also an option. This eliminates the need to notify attendees in advance that they want to attend the meeting at a specific time.

[image]

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, that's what I had thought since the links never expire.

Comment: Yes, this is very easy compared to other settings or scripts.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create a reoccurring meeting. Set it to repeat `Monthly`, then select the date.

[image]